What could be the possible reasons of "Access denied" error while attempting to open a handle to a Windows device?
ioctlbf is an IOCTL fuzzer for Windows. Given a target devicem it opens up a handle to it like this:
deviceHandle = CreateFile((HANDLE) deviceName,
  GENERIC_READ,
  0,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  0,
  NULL);
if (deviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  printf("FAILED, error code: %d\n%s\n", GetLastError(),
    errorCode2String(GetLastError()));
  exit(1);
}

The device is created like this:
drvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = ...;
drvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = ...;
drvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL] = ...;
drvObj->DriverExtension->AddDevice = ...;
drvObj->DriverUnload = NULL;

IoCreateDevice(drvObj, 0, &dName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, TRUE, &devObj);

The problem is, even when I am running the tool from administrator console, I am getting "Access is denied, Error code 5". I am not familiar with Windows driver programming. Where should I be looking at to investigate this? Could it anyway be related to protected process / ACL / Exclusive bit in IoDeviceCreate?

Ran ioctlbf deom administrator console so that the privilege does not become an issue
The device is marked as "Exclusive", but current handle count in DeviceTree is 0. So, I guess that the number of handle is not the issue here
Tried other tools like ioctlpus


How is the device created in the driver?

@Luke Edited the original post

What is the exact value of deviceName you're using? How did you get or open it? (If it's a HANDLE then why is it named like it's a string?) Similarly, what is dName? Does the driver code check the return-value from IoCreateDevice?

Does the IRP_MJ_CREATE handler do anything other than return success? Try adding some logging there to see if something else is accessing the device.

@Luke The issue is that I cannot modfy the code, only view it
